# Get value from a SPARQL query

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, rdfa

The following query is sufficient for me to get the name of a recipe and the amount of ingredients in it. I would like to get the ingredients in the recipe as well.  How can I modify my query to do this?

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>
select ?r (count(distinct ?Ingrediente) as ?oi) ?i {
  ?r rec:Ingrediente ?Ingrediente
  filter not exists {
    ?r rec:Ingrediente ?other_ingredient
    filter( ?other_ingredient not in (rec:Cebolla,rec:Tomate, rec:Aceite, rec:Sal, rec:Lechuga) )
  }
}
group by ?r ?i
order by (count(distinct ?Ingrediente))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is of course just adding the variable you want to have the values of, `?Ingrediente`, to your `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT ?r (count(distinct ?Ingrediente) as ?oi) ?Ingrediente
```

(as an aside, you have a variable `?i` in there which doesn't seem to do anything - it's never bound to a value. I'll just ignore that variable from now on)

However, since you are using aggregates and a grouping, this requires that you also add the variable to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY ?r ?Ingrediente
```

This will probably, more or less, work, but a problem is that you are mixing an aggregate (the count of number of ingredients) and the individual values of that aggregate. You will get an awful lot of near-duplicate rows in your result (one for every ingredient per recipe), and due to the change in the grouping it's possible that the count is now wrong, too.

So - alternative approach needed. What you can do is use a `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function. This picks all values and concatenates them into a single (space-separated, at least by default) list. If you use this you also won't have to adjust the `GROUP BY` clause. As follows:

```
SELECT ?r (count(distinct ?Ingrediente) as ?oi) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?Ingrediente) as ?List)
```

The result will looks something like this:

```
  ?r          ?oi                ?List 
  :r1           3                "rec:Tomate rec:Sal rec:Aceita"
```

The list will probably contain full URIs rather than prefixed names, but you get the idea. Of course, if you want the names of the ingredients rather than their URIs, you need to query those names by matching the appropriate property (e.g. `rdfs:label`), and then using the `GROUP_CONCAT` on that property value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation! Its really useful! As you mentioned, if I use the GROUP_CONCAT I get just one ingredient per recipe, and if I use the group by then I have problems with the count, because in that column I get 1 on each row

Comment: @KarenWiznia no problem. By the way, rather than thanking me in a comment, it's more usual to indicate an answer was useful to you by upvoting and/or accepting it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers